# Using Visual Studio Windows Form Designer for other than Forms (like panels or otner)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm relatively new to c# and Visual Studio.

In my application I have a TabControl and the user is able to create as many TabPages as he whants, when the user add a page, my program automaticaly create a large quantity of controls inside this page with many and many lines writed by myself.

My question is: Is there a way to create my TabPage at Design Time with Form Designer (as I can do with the forms) so that the code is autogenerated ?  And then use this "prefrabbicated" component (my TabPage) with a line like this?

```
pag1 = new myCustom_TabPage(...) ?
```

I tried to create a class of type TabPage like this

```
public class Vista_Tabulato_Pagina : TabPage
{
    public Vista_Tabulato_Pagina(VISTE vista)
    {
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
```

but when I hit Shift+F7 to invoke the Designer It show a blank screen and when I put some component inside it will not show realy visually that I can resize ecc but only a block for every components, (like when you put a non visual component inside a form designer) you can click and edit properties but thats all

Thanks,
Luca.

Comment: You can create a new class and inherit it from `TabPage`. Visual Designer should be available

Comment: That doesn't work, the designer for TabPage is rolled up in the designer for TabControl and it only knows about TabPage.  Most practical approach is to design a UserControl for each tab page.

Comment: @AleksAndreev I tried, I created a class inheridet from TabPage and when I hit Shift+F7 to invoke the Designer It show a blank screen and when I put some component inside it will not show realy visually that I can resize ecc but only a block for every components, (like when you put a non visual component inside a form designer) you can click and edit properties but thats all

Comment: @HansPassant thanks but what do you mean when you say "design a UserControl" ?

Comment: Add a control to your project instead of a form, it should inherit from `UserControl` instead of `Form`. It will have a designer. A user control can be added to a tabpage just like any other control.

Comment: Thaks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that what I missed !!!   Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Yep! Excuse my VB, make a class that inherits from TabPage:

```
Public Class chicken
    Inherits TabPage
    Sub New()
        Me.Controls.Add(New TextBox With {.Text = "Im a textbox!"})
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then hack the designer file, replacing one of the old TabPages with your new class:

```
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.TabControl1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
        Me.TabPage1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
        Me.TabPage2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
        Me.TabPage3 = New chicken
        … etc
```

Then after a rebuild it'll appear on the designer, and more can be added by using just:

```
Me.TabControl1.Controls.Add(New chicken)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to C# and I've some limitation about this, moreover if you write in VB I can't realy understand.... sorry :-(

Comment: Do you want me to translate it for you? Or are you willing to translate it yourself? The technique has been written in ENGLISH with the code being an example. You have been shown the solution, the rest is up to you.  -.-